# What is webpartid2?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, web-parts

For example I have html for webpart like this:

```
<div class="ms-WPBody noindex " id="WebPartWPQ2" 
webpartid="7de980df-9385-4e4c-9dc2-a518e968df1c"  
webpartid2="4cb90c96-ea5a-41db-ac5b-6770451267a5">
```

what is the difference between webpartid and webpartid2 ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Web Part into a page, the web part reference is registered with the web part manager. However, if you perform a redirect before saving the page, for example, edit the web part, the web part ID will lose link to the web part reference, because all the variables in the current page will be cleared, thus a new ID will be generated and assigned.